# Приложение калькулятор на Andoid. Почему приложение выдает ошибку?

Tags: java, android

Есть метод, который проверяет 2 поля на наличие текста, при нажатии на кнопку "**=**". Если одно из полей пустое - должно выводиться всплывающее окно, в противном случае происходит вычисление. При первых вычислениях все корректно работает. Но при вторичном нажатии на "**=**" приложение крашится. firstNumberView и secondNumbeeView являются объектами типа TextView

```
public void onOperandClick(View view) {
    Button button = (Button) view;
    pointButton.setEnabled(true);

    switch (button.getText().toString()) {
        case "+":
            operandView.setText("+");
            break;
        case "-":
            operandView.setText("-");
            break;
        case "*":
            operandView.setText("*");
            break;
        case "/":
            operandView.setText("/");
            break;
        case "=":
            if (firstNumberView.getText().equals("") || secondNumberView.getText().equals("")) {
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Input all numbers", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();
                break;
            } else {
                calculate();
                firstNumberView.setText("");
                operandView.setText("");
                secondNumberView.setText("");
                break;
            }
    }
```

Comment: Выдает ошибку? Какую?

Comment: посмотрите в вкладке logcat, там во время падения будет много красного текста со ссылкой на активность, приложите текст логов и строку на которую указывает ошибка

Comment: и класс приложите, а то сложно понять какие виджеты используются

Comment: @Andrew ошибка NumberFormatException в методе calculate.. но, проблема не в этом. Объекты firstNumberView и secondNumberView являются объектами TextView. При повторном нажатии на "=" блок if игнорируется. А в методе calculate() текст парсится в double, оттого и NumberFormatException, так как компилятор не может спарсить пустую строку. Вопрос, почему блок if игнорируется?

Comment: если проблема в calculate то почему не приложить код метода и текста ошибки??? и каким образом вы вводите текста в textView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я думаю основная ошибка не в «пропуске» if-блока, а в первоначальном исполнении. Вот:

```
f.setText("");
//Ваше действие setText("");
f.getText();
//Вернёт null
f.getText().toString();
//Вернёт ""
```

Я думаю, что надо сравнивать не с пустой строкой, а с null (или примените toString() и сравнивайте с пустой строкой)